# Как изменить модель нейронной сети чтобы повысить точность mAP не обучая с 0 , а только дообучая

Tags: нейронные-сети, tensorflow

как можно изменить модель Faster R-CNN Resnet 101 или Faster R-CNN Inception Resnet V2 чтобы повысить точность обнаружения mAP , при этом не обучая модель с 0 , а дообучая уже обученную

может есть какие то подходы , хотя бы название этих подходов чтоб почитать